# Show that $G(x)$ is differentiable, Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f: [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$ be continuous and $v: [c,d] \to \Bbb{R}$ be differentiable and let $v(J) \subseteq I$. Show that if $ G: J =[c ,d] \to \Bbb{R}$ is defined by 
$G(x) = \int_a^{v(x)}f(t)dt, x \in J$, then $G$ is  differentiable and find $G'(x)$.

I can find $G'(x)$, but I don't understand how to show that $G(x)$ is differentiable in the first place. Would it be sufficient to just submit the derivative as my answer?

Comment: What is $v(x)$?

Comment: Is $f$ continuous ?

Comment: The proposition is false without assumptions on $v$ and $f$.  Even if you assume $f$ is continuous you can make a lazy example with $f(t) = 1$ and $v(x)$ some non-differentiable function.  Example, $v(x) = x^{2/3}$, $a = c = -1$, $d= 1$, $\int_a^{v(x)} f(t) \, dt = x^{2/3} +1$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: ^ you work too fast. just fixed it.

Comment: Chain Rule.$ F(x)=\int_a^x f(y)\;dy$ and $G(x)=F(v(x))$ so $G'(x)=F'(v(x))\cdot v'(x)=f(v(x))\cdot v'(x).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do need to prove the differentiability of $G$. Here is the proof:

\begin{align}
G'(x) & = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac {G(x + \Delta x) - G(x)}{\Delta x} && \text{definition of derivatives}\\
 & = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac {\int_a^{v(x + \Delta x)} f(t)\mathop{\mathrm{d}t} - \int_a^{v(x)} f(t)\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}{\Delta x} && \text{definition of $G$}\\
 & = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac {\int_{v(x)}^{v(x + \Delta x)} f(t)\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}{\Delta x} && \text{additivity of integration on intervals}\\
 & = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac {F(v(x + \Delta x))-F(v(x))}{\Delta x} && \text{fundamental theorem of calculus} \\
\end{align}

where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$. $F(x)$ exists because $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$. Remember that *all real-valued continuous functions on the closed and bounded interval $[a, b]$ are Riemann integrable.*

For $G$ to be differentiable, we need only show that $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac {F(v(x + \Delta x))-F(v(x))}{\Delta x}$ exists, that is, $F \circ v$ is differentiable (by definition of derivatives).

Here is what we already know: $F$ is differentiable and $F'(x) = f(x)$. $v$ is also differentiable (given) and $v(J) \subseteq I = [a, b]$. Observe that the range of $F$ is just the range of $f$, that is, $[a, b]$. Thus,

$$\operatorname{im}(v) \subseteq \operatorname{dom}(f) = \operatorname{dom}(F).$$

This shows that the domain of $F \circ v$ is just $I$. Now it is obvious that $F \circ v$ is differentiable on the interval $I$ from the well-known theorem that *if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $g$ is differentiable at $f(a)$, then $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $a$*. This concludes the proof.

Comment: In your text paragraph you quite use a few theorems without naming them, fundamental theorem of calc, chain rule etc.

Comment: @Imago I just added those remarks. Thank you.

Comment: very good answer :). It deserved more up votes as the only mean of appreciation here on M.SE. (Unfortunately there isn't yet another way)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from the title like you know the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is what tells you that 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t) \, dt = f(x)$$
(under assumptions), in other words that the integral on the left is differentiable and the derivative can be computed easily.

For the problem you are asking the challenge is how to justify that an integral with a function as an endpoint is still differentiable.  Consider writing $I(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$, so that $G(x) = I(v(x))$.  Then since both $I$ and $v$ are differentiable the chain rule applies and the composition is differentiable with derivative $I'(v(x))v'(x)$.

Comment: How is $I$ differentiable? I regard this as the main issue in this exercise.